# node App not reachable from outside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Im having troubles while trying to access my NodeJs app on a container.

Resume:
I customized my own image to run pm2 and loopback on my container. 
I configured my app to listen to a mongodb on another container within a docker network. **This works fine.**
I created my docker-compose.yml file to looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  webapp:
    expose:
      - "3000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ${NODEJS_PATH}:${NODEJS_PATH_DESTIONATION}
    image: ${CUSTOMIZED_IMAGE}
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: ${NODEJS_IP}

  db:
    image: mongo:4.2.6
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ${MONGO_SCRIPT_PATH}:${MONGO_SCRIPT_DESTINATION_PATH}
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: ${MONGO_INITDB_IP}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${CUSTOMIZED_NET}
```

I ran my webapp with docker-compose run webapp for now for customize purposes. 
Inside this container I execute the next cmd

```
pm2 start app.js --env environment_variables
```

It runs the NodeJS App on http://localhost:3000 **inside the docker**

I tried to check this from a browser http://{DOCKER_IP}:3000 but it's not working.

I would be eternally grateful with any answer to this trouble.

Comment: First to check, remove `network` tab and put `network_mode: "host"` and then run and try to access `localhost:3000`

Comment: Thx for the answer, It works the way you said.

Answer (score 0):

We used nginx to proxy_pass the service from the docker to the outside world.

We did it this way because we need other services on the docker_network to listen to this one.

Here is the config from the nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.local;

        location /  {
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```